# Prove that $f\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\ln x_{i}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)$ is convex

Tags: logarithms, convex-analysis

Im trying to prove that $f\colon\mathbb{R}_{++}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$
defined by
$$
f\left(x\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\ln x_{i}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)
$$
is a convex function. What I thought about is using some of the ln
properties which can give us
\begin{align*}
f\left(x\right) & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\ln x_{i}-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)=\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\ln x_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)=\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\left(\ln x_{i}-\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)\right)=\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\ln\left(\frac{x_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}}\right)
\end{align*}
and it suffices to show that $f_{i}\left(x\right)=x_{i}\ln\left(\frac{x_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}}\right)$
is convex. But using the Hessian criterion for this function seemed
to me like an overkill. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it suffices to show that $f_{i}\left(x\right)=x_{i}\ln\left(\frac{x_{i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}}\right)$
>   is convex

Since, $g(x) = x\log x$ is convex, the perspective $y g(x/y) = x\log (x/y)$ is also convex. Taking $y=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}$ does not affect convexity.